# The accessible_by call cannot be used with a block 'can' definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, cancancan

It is very interesting that I am not using a block inside can declaration, but I got this error when I open active admin. I've no idea how to fix it.

```rb
[:forename, :surname, :biography, :country].each do |attr_name|
  can :read, User, attr_name,
    id: User.joins(:visibilities)
      .where(visibilities: { level: "public", attribute_name: attr_name })
      .pluck(:id)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an ability uniquely for active admin, where I didn't use this kind of authorisation, and a different one for the frontend.